# Coordinates only users geolocation in RoR 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I'm looking for a solution to build very simple geolocation-based app. It should keep current user location, and select users near specific coordinates. So I don't need a solution, based on foursquare or google map apis, I need something more simple.

Now I have model user, which have :lat and :long fields, and query like this:

```
"SELECT lat, long FROM users WHERE long < :lolow AND long > :lohigh AND lat < :lalow AND long > :lahigh"
```

Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I think your where clause should be:  long > :lolow and long < :lohigh and lat > :lalow and lat < :lahigh.  As written, it will return no values (because long has to be less than :lolow and also greater than :lohigh).  Also, the last clause compares long to :lahigh.

Comment: Yes, it was written too fast. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution. I used location => type:point.
And SQL code:

```
def self.next_to_me(coordinates, distance)
where( "circle :which @> location AND updated_at > :time",
                                                   :which => "<(#{coordinates}),#{distance}>",
                                                   :time => 20.minutes.ago ).limit(100)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem inelegant to me.  Perhaps you find this more aesthetically pleasing:

```
SELECT lat, long
FROM users
WHERE long not between :lolow AND :lohigh AND
      lat not between  :lalow AND :lahigh
```

"not between" is one of those things that almost never gets used in SQL, but it is there for using.  You could also say "not (long between :lolow and :lohigh)"

Actually, I suspect you don't mean not between at all and you really mean "between":

```
SELECT lat, long
FROM users
WHERE long between :lolow AND :lohigh AND
      lat between  :lalow AND :lahigh
```

Your original query would return nothing when the "low" values are numerically less than the "high" values.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the db engine you're using - I use MySQL. you should have a look at the 'Spatial' field types. You could store the lat-long as a point an then query to see if it falls within Polygon. E.g I have a 5000 point polygon which I query to see if any points fall within.